# XLSXWriter Format multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

Trying to do something that should be simple. XLSXWriter has a function set_column that lets me format multiple columns at the same time:

worksheet.set_column('B:D', 30, align)

However, there is no such row function, as

worksheet.set_row(5,None, percentage)

operates on but one row at a time.

I've tried doing the following to no avail:

worksheet.conditional_format('C27:W27', {'format': percentage})

How can I simply set cells C27:W27 to be percentage format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, a method such as worksheet.set_row(5,None, percentage) does not exist. I ended up scrapping this project.